# Vertical alignment of Date in DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, vertical-alignment

I'm using a DatePicker in WPF and would like to vertically align the text to the center of the DatePicker.

Is there any way to do this, short of writing my own DatePicker?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
[image: To visualize my poblem:]

Comment: in `WPF DatePicker` date in textbox is already vertically aligned . what do you want ?

Comment: i want to align the text inside the textbox to the center of the textbox

Comment: this doesn't work `DatePicker.Text.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center` ?

Comment: Maybe we are talking about different DatePicker? I'm using the System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker. This has .Text, but that has no VerticalAlignment.

Comment: Check my answer please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in XAML add style to `DatePickerTextBox` of `DatePicker`  it should work.

```
<DatePicker Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="45" Background="White"
            FontSize="8" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">

    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>

</DatePicker>
```

Comment: This soltuion will always work if you play with height or font property even.

Comment: Yes i tried and then suggested you this because Editing TEMPLATE is not the most excellent way of making small changes. Edit Template only in case when you want to alter the style of an element.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I definitley learned some useful things today.

Comment: Good to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it looks better if you keep the font size to 12 and apply a scale to the DatePickers LayoutTransform, while my second choice would be to template out the whole thing. To answer your question though, a quick and easy solution is to add a `Loaded` handler in the parent window/control's constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    theDatePicker.Loaded += TheDatePicker_Loaded;
}
```

And then override the button's vertical alignment in the handler:

```
private void TheDatePicker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = theDatePicker.Template.FindName("PART_Button", theDatePicker) as Button;
    button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
}
```

Comment: unfortunatly 'button' is null. Maybe because i don't define any templates? Or maybe "PART_Button" is wrong?

Comment: You are doing it in the Loaded handler and not the constructor, right? If so that would suggest that something has overloaded the default template and removed PART_Button ('s definitely part of the standard WPF template for both Core and Standard). Try putting the mouse cursor on the DatePicker in the XAML, then go to properties, click the little square to the right of Miscellaneous -> Template and select "Convert to Local Value". That will automatically template out the control for you and remove any other template that's being applied. You should also see PART_Button in that template.

Comment: One other thing....check whether `FindName` is returning anything at all prior to casting it to type Button, could be that whatever GUI framework you're using has replaced it with something else.

Comment: FindName already returns null; But the Template shows up like you said and it has "PART_Button". How can i find out, if and where the template is replaced?

Comment: Also, now that the code of the template is visible, i get an error:
     Index 0 is out of range of the PathParameters list, which has length 0. NotesSetup.xaml 141 

The program still runs though.
I also tried changing the value directly in the template (setting verticalAlignment od PART_Button to center) . It didn't change anything

Comment: Strange, just tried it myself and got the same error, looks like the control templating for DatePicker is broken, at least in 2019. This works though: grab [the template code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datepicker-styles-and-templates) from the MS site. There's two styles on that page, put the second one (DatePicker) in your resources block and remove any existing style/template from your control.

Comment: Setting the PART_Button vertical alignment using that method does work for me, so if it's still not working for you then that would again point to something setting a new template, in which case try looking at the DatePicker's Live Visual Tree while your application is running and see what it's template is being set to.

Comment: Your way worked too. I only needed to change PART_TextBox instead od PART_Button.  If you want to, please post the answer.